# ERROR MailServiceIT.testSendEmailFromTemplate:143

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-integration, jhipster

I'm using JHipster 7.6.0 (Spring boot + React), when I run integration tests I got the following error. I searched on the internet but I have found nothing
Thanks in advance!

```
[ERROR]   MailServiceIT.testSendEmailFromTemplate:143 
expected: "test title"
 but was: "Activation de votre compte gestionUtilisateurs"
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 225, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:report-integration (post-integration-tests) @ gestion-utilisateurs ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Users\ASUS\.jenkins\workspace\apisation portnet\target\jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Gestion Utilisateurs' with 83 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.2:check (default) @ gestion-utilisateurs ---
[INFO] You have 0 Checkstyle violations.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) @ gestion-utilisateurs ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-21T14:36:42+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) on project gestion-utilisateurs: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: If you haven't modified anything, this looks like a bug that you should report on github with appropriate details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure happens if you choose French as a native language of the application. I reported this on JHipster GitHub repository. Also I mentioned how did I solve it so that the integration test won't fail.
here is the details of the failure:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/17946

You can find my solution for the problem in **Suggest a Fix**
section in the link above

**UPDATE**

this issue is fixed since JHipster versoin `7.9.0`